# Mock function not getting called in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test:

```
onChange(value) {
  this.setState({ postcode: value });
  if (value.length >= 3) this.listSuggestions(value);
}
```

by writing:

```
test("onChange updates the state", () => {
  const postalCodeWrapper = mount(<PostalCode />);
  const instance = postalCodeWrapper.instance();
  const listSuggestions = jest.fn(instance.listSuggestions);

  const mockValue = "this is mock value";
  instance.onChange(mockValue);
  expect(instance.state.postcode).toBe(mockValue);
  expect(listSuggestions).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And this returns `Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.`, talking about `listSuggestions`. Why is that? Same thing happens if I remove the `if (value.length >= 3)` statement.

Comment: Shouldn't `const listSuggestions = jest.fn(instance.listSuggestions)` be `instance.listSuggestions = jest.fn(instance.listSuggestions)`?

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you! That worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
const listSuggestions = jest.fn(instance.listSuggestions);
```

When you call that, `jest.fn` is returning a *new* function, not mutating the existing method. You assign it to a `const`, but your component will be calling the original.

Change it to:

```
instance.listSuggestions = jest.fn(instance.listSuggestions);
```

To overwrite the component method with the mock function, which it will then call assuming the conditional check passes.